# Super admin access to Huawei HG8245

Tags: router, wireless-router, internet-connection

When I'm connecting to the HG8245's web interface as root/admin, I get only partial access to some of the router options.

I've tried resetting the router settings and connecting to the router via telnet (i.e. telnet 192.168.100.1 23) to find out the super admin account in the config file but with no luck.

Is there any way I could factory reset the router or get super admin access?

Comment: Is this an ISP supplied router?

Comment: Yes. It was pre-configured by them.

Comment: Then it will be a custom ROM with restricted access to the end user - probably to stop users screwing up and losing their internet and/or to restrict port forwarding so that the ISP can control what services are exposed, and potentially charged for.The ISP will have retained full access.

Comment: So I assume it's not possible to get super user access without their intrusion?

Comment: Quite likely...

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried logging in as user `telecomadmin` and pass `admintelecom`? It's a default hardcoded user // pass for Huawei HG8245/HG8245T and as far as I know it's not possible to even change this user's password (at least not from the web UI), which is quite ridiculous!

Comment: is there a way to change this telecomadmin password? Or its for local login only?

Comment: No idea, I can only access my huawei from the UI and I can't find anything about this user there. Just to be sure I've forwarded my public ip port 80 to a home machine :)

Comment: The issue is that this user only exists when no GPON is connected. Once the router has WAN access, the provider will replace the config with their own, therefore losing the `telecomadmin` access. I though that I finally managed to break through, only to realize I am still not a bit closer to getting root shell and dumping the transciever info.

Answer (score 4):

### Getting the router's config

Looks like Huawei uses the same encryption key on the configs for all routers and according to a [Spanish language forum](https://www.underground.org.mx/index.php?topic=27777.180) it was present in a file on the router /etc/wap/aes_string.

I have found the [source code](https://github.com/palmerc/AESCrypt2) for the tool [aescrypt2_huawei](https://zedt.eu/storage/2016/02/aescrypt2_huawei.zip) that is provided and a walk-through provided on a blog called [TheZedt](https://zedt.eu/tech/hardware/obtaining-administrator-access-huawei-hg8247h/). It seems the Huawei uses the same configuration encryption key `hex:13395537D2730554A176799F6D56A239` on all of its devices and the only thing special about the binary version of the tool is the fact it adds an 8-byte header to the file. You can see the source code link for a more detailed explanation.

As the walkthrough and @Blz mentions you can modify the `UserLevel` to `0` and reupload it to the router, but... I strongly recommend you add a new user rather than modify an existing account. You'll need to generate a new password hash using the formula SHA256(MD5(new password)). Test to make sure you can generate the same hash as the root account in the file by testing with 'admin'.

On a Mac

```
echo -n admin | md5 | tr -d '\n' | shasum -a 256
```

yields

```
465c194afb65670f38322df087f0a9bb225cc257e43eb4ac5a0c98ef5b3173ac
```

in the file

```
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="1" UserName="root" Password="465c194afb65670f38322df087f0a9bb225cc257e43eb4ac5a0c98ef5b3173ac" UserLevel="1" Enable="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" PassMode="2" />
```

Hashes match.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get admin access. Login to web interface as root/admin. Download existing configuration (**System tools -> Configuration file** and click on **Download configuration file**). Open downloaded file with text editor. It depends on you firmware version whether configuration file will be encrypted or not. If your text editor shows [XML data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJuvG.png)  then just search for **root** or **X_HW_WebUserInfo** and modify existing records or add a new one.

```
<X_HW_WebUserInfo NumberOfInstances="2">
    <X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="1" UserName="root" Password="secterPass" UserLevel="0"/>
    <X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="2" UserName="blizz" Password="myPassword" UserLevel="0"/>
</X_HW_WebUserInfo>
```

( **UserLevel="0"** means that user has admin rights. If you add a new record don't forget to change value of **NumberOfInstances** )

Then just upload updated configuration file via web interface (**System tools -> Configuration file**)

But, if configuration file encrypted you should follow steps in [this tutorial](http://www.zedt.eu/tech/hardware/obtaining-administrator-access-huawei-hg8247h/).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the password for telecomadmin that is the default admin account for Huawei HG8245 by updating the routers configuration file. You can even make the root account an administrator account and even add new ones.

For more information refer to this website
https://zedt.eu/tech/hardware/obtaining-administrator-access-huawei-hg8247h/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.