# deciphering Huawei hg8245h modem sip phone password

Tags: router, modem, decryption

I have a Huawei hg8245h modem and unfortunately, I have forgotten my sip phone password and my ISP does not provide it to me. I have downloaded the modem configuration and this is the section related to the SIP password:

```
<SIP AuthUserName="XXXX" AuthPassword="XXXX" URI="">
<X_HW_Digitmap DMName="" DigitMap="" DigitMapStartTimer="20" DigitMapShortTimer="5" DigitMapLongTimer="10"/>
</SIP>
```

I have tried to use this tool to decipher with no success:
https://andreluis034.github.io/huawei-utility-page/#cipher

How can I decipher it?

Comment: If the device uses a unique salt, and the password is hashed, what you want is virtually impossible unless you happen to find a password collision. Hashing algorithms strictly speaking cannot be decipher.  The reason you can provide say a MD5, and a website can provide a text based word to you, is MD5 password collisions exist.

Comment: This is not impossible for the hg8245h routers. I pointed to a tool that does exactly the same thing, but it doesn't work for my password value. The tool I provided doesn't use MD5 password collisions. This link is a similar question where users have answered a similar question and extracted the password:
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31663/decrypt-pppoe-password-of-huawei-ont-hg8145v5?rq=1

Comment: MD5 was an example. SHA256 is also a hashing which cannot be reversed.

Comment: According to the answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1283258
It seems the Huawei uses the same configuration encryption key hex:13395537D2730554A176799F6D56A239 on all of its devices

Comment: 4 years dealing with encryption may as well be 40 years.  Have you verified the key is the same by viewing ` /etc/wap/aes_string`?

Comment: The main fact that proves that decryption is possible is that the modem needs the plain-test version of the password to function correctly. Therefore it needs to somehow decrypt it. The interesting observation that the community has mentioned is that the modems have the same encryption key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tool mentioned here:
https://github.com/hu60t/hu60wap6/files/6206916/Huawei.configuration.encryption.and.decryption.tools.zip

Reference: https://gist.github.com/staaldraad/605a5e40abaaa5915bc7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).